Correct way to use from_euler function of Scipy
Having Phi, Psi, and Theta in euler angle system and knowing the convention is 'zyz', In what order should I pass the angle to from_euler function of scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation package to get the correct rotation matrix of the object?
